# To check given set is closed and bounded set?

Tags: real-analysis

> The set $\{x\in \Bbb R:x\sin x\le1,x\cos x\le1\}\subseteq \Bbb R $ is:
>
> 1. A bounded closed set.
> 2. A unbounded closed set.
> 3. A bounded open set.
> 4. A unbounded open set.

I guess answer is 1 because given set is compact as we take sequence $\left(\frac1n\right)$ in a given set and $\frac1n \to 0$ is a limit point of a set and belongs to given set. Hence given set is closed. Is it correct? Please tell me the correct answer.

Comment: You need to prove that every limit point of the set belongs to the set, not just $0$.

Comment: You should prove that for every convergent sequence of the set and not just one specific sequence.

Comment: What about proving $f(x)= (x\sinx,x\cosx)$ is continuous, thus the preimage of a closed set is closed?

Comment: @LiChunMin I thought we only have "preimage of open set is open".

Comment: I thought this is equivalent to preimage of closed set is closed.

Comment: I thought that is only equivalent to "image of closed set is closed"

Answer (score 2):

1. The set is unbounded. Show that $\{(2m+1) \pi: m \in \mathbb N\}$ is a subset of the given set $A$.
2. Let $f(x)=x \sin x$ and $g(x)= x \cos x$. Then

$$A= f^{-1}((- \infty,1 ]) \cap g^{-1}((- \infty,1 ]).$$ Since $f$ and $g$ are continuous and $(- \infty,1 ]$ is closed, $A$ is closed.

Comment: Yes I got it.Thanks